# Dealing with variables with gettext function

Tags: custom-post-types, translation

I've found tweaking some of the text in WordPress to be pretty easy by adding in the following function (in lieu of using a separate plugin):

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'of_site_translations', 9999, 2 );
function of_site_translations( $translation, $text ) {
if ( $text == 'Posts' )
        return 'News Posts';
return $translation;
}
```

The issue I'm running into is (in my above example) while it will change `Posts` to `News Posts` in the WP Sidebar - areas that are dynamically created based on the post type labels; when you click on `Posts` from the sidebar and it leads you to a page that says `Posts`. Is there a way to override post type labels using this method? If so, any pointers that could push me along a bit? Really appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just rename the labels associated with that post type.

```
class News_Post_Type {
    const POST_TYPE = 'post';

    public static function init() {
        $post_obj = get_post_type_object('post');
        $post_obj->labels->name = __('News Post', 'textdomain');
        $post_obj->labels->singular_name = __('News Post', 'textdomain');
        // You can continue to rename all the label properties, this is just an example
    }
}

add_action( 'init', array( 'News_Post_Type', 'init' ) );
```

Comment: Wow! I had no idea this was possible. Was this something you also stumbled upon, or is there something in the codex I maybe missed about this? Really appreciate it!

Comment: Had to do the same thing at work and it was suggestion from a co-worker.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the theme you are using and how well it is using WordPress' string translations. Any text wrapped in translation strings can be modified using the `gettext` filter. Check this link for more information on translation strings -> http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers